# Entity Framework One to One Fluent Api Can not Delete Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-nhibernate

That is the Gift class in model. That should be the parent class.

```
public class Gift
    {
        public int GiftId { get; set; }           
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public bool Chosen { get; set; }   
        public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }    
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }        
    }
```

That is the Shop class and these two have one to one relationship. A gift shoud have a shop, and a shop should have a gift.

```
public class Shop
    {
        public int ShopId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string District { get; set; }  
        public virtual Gift Gift { get; set; }
    }
```

That is the third class in my model. This class has one to zero relationship with the gift class. If a gift is not chosen, it does not have any person. Same for the person too.

```
 public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
    public string EmailAdress { get; set; }
    public virtual Gift Gift { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the fluent api that i have lots of times changed.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Gift>()
                .HasOptional(x => x.Person);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Gift);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Gift>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Shop).WithOptional(x => x.Gift).Map(x => x.MapKey("ShopId"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<Shop>()
               .HasRequired(x => x.Gift).WithOptional(x => x.Shop).Map(x => x.MapKey("GiftId"));
```

I can save data but when i want to delete a gift, i can not succeed and have problems. How can i fix that? Thanx already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it. [Here is the link](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-one-to-one-mapping/)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Shop>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Gift)
                .WithRequiredDependent();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gift>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Shop)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```